# Test Callback in an activity with Robolectric

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, callback, robolectric

I have issues to test a callback in an activity using Robolectric.

I have one activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public static String value;
public Handler sHandler;

public Handler.Callback sHandlerCallback = new Handler.Callback(){

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        value = "SEND_REQUEST_MSG";
        changeName();
        return true;

    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("estat");
    handlerThread.start();
    sHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper(), sHandlerCallback);

}

public void sendMessage()
{
    sHandler.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();
}

public void changeName()
{
    runOnUiThread (new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView t= (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textToDisplay);
            t.setText(value);
        }
    }));

}}
```

and one test using Robolectric :

```
@RunWith(CustomRobolectricRunner.class)
public class TestApplicationTest {

private MainActivity activity;

@Test
public void testCreateMainActivity() throws InterruptedException {

    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();

    Button pressMeButton = (Button) activity.findViewById(R.id.button);

    pressMeButton.performClick();

    Robolectric.runBackgroundTasks();
    Robolectric.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();

    assertEquals("SEND_REQUEST_MSG", activity.value);

}}
```

So the fact is when I launch the activity from my phone, when I click the button specified in the activity we call the method sendMessage and add a Message to the queue. This message is handle by the method handleMessage in the callback which change the attribute value and call ChangeName().

But when I execute the test from command line with ./gradlew clean build. The test fails with an assertion error that tells me the value is null !

So can we test callBack with Robolectric ?

Thanks you very much !

Comment: Can you explain why do you need such complex construction in Activity? `Robolectric.runBackgroundTask()` will execute all postponed `AsyncTasks`. However you doing setup another thread and you need different way of synchronization. As well I'm not sure if `static` modifier makes variable change visible in different threads

Comment: I did not give you the methods which need to be synchronized. I wanted to show that when I run this on my phone, the handleMessage is run whereas with Robolectric it is not. So the static modifier for the value is well seen. The only problem is that Robolectric is not able to run callbacks and I don't know why!

Comment: Just for checking can you add `Thread.wait(10000)` before your assert line?

Comment: It might not work I should look to Robolectric code. Here is another way to test similar situation http://johnnydew.blogspot.nl/2013/11/unit-testing-android-handler-using.html

Comment: The Thread.wait(1000) is not working and I already tried the solution on the link you gave me :p